# Revalidate DIV's dimensions when window resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to revalidate the size of a div when the window gets resized.

I have a div that has a height of 100% and a width of 100% and when i resize the window, I can see a part of the div underneath this one.

A perfect example of what i want to get is this site :

http://maltedemuth.com/

When you resize it vertically, you see the top of the second part of the site but then, it revalidates the size of the first div.

---

Edit :

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="background-color:black;height:100%;width:100%;">DIV1</div>
<div style="background-color:blue;height:100%;width:100%;">DIV2</div>
</body>
```

Here's the type of code I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you gave, uses [Full Page jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

To achieve the effect, you need to follow the basic layout given on the plugin's *GITHUB* page and then while initializing, use `verticalCentered: true` option.

Their description says it all:

> verticalCentered: (default true) Vertically centering of the content within sections. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve a full page scroll effect thats also responsive? If so I recommend checking out [one page scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll). This will give you a similar effect to the example you posted. It's also really easy to setup and comes with lots of options you can customise you make it as responsive as you see fit.

Comment: Hi woolm, that's not the feature I'm looking for but thx for the answer.